# gcloud cmd line add ssl certificat to lb

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I'm using a Google Cloud Platform load balancer to redirect my HTTP and HTTPS traffic.
For the SSL cert I'm using letsencrypt.
I have a cron to refresh the cert and upload it on gcloud.

I'm looking for a way to add / replace the cert on a the load balancer like in the UI.
[image: edit / update ssl cert load balancer]

My current script

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script must be run as root or sudo

cert_path=/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.co
project_ids=("domain-xxxxx")
date=`date +%d-%m-%Y`
certname="domain-cert-${date}"

lb_cert() {
  # Multiples projects
  for project_id in "${project_ids[@]}"; do
    gcloud config set project $project_id
    gcloud compute ssl-certificates create $certname --certificate "${cert_path}/cert.pem" --private-key "${cert_path}/privkey.pem"
  done
}

certbot renew --quiet

if [[ "$?" -ne 0 ]]; then
  lb_cert
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the SSL certificate, you must update the target HTTP proxy with the new certificate:

```
gcloud compute target-https-proxies update $https_proxy_name --ssl-certificates=$certname
```